# What's the order of the difference of these two terms involving square root?

Tags: limits, inequality

Can we prove the following statement:

As $x \rightarrow \infty$, and $y<x$
$$\sqrt{x-y}-(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}) = o(1)$$

Comment: What is the $o(1)$ taken with regard to? What variables ($x,y$?) goes to what ($\infty,0,a\in\mathbb{R}$?)?

Comment: I think he means as $x,y\to \infty$ the expression never exceeds a constant.

Comment: $o(1)$ would mean it actually goes to 0. But while it makes sense for it to be when either $x$ or $y$ (or both?) goes to $\infty$, right now the question is not fully specified.

Comment: Thank you for your notice. I have just modified my question.

Comment: It does not seem to be true for $y=c$ or $y=x-c$ with $0 \lt c$ (both increase towards $\sqrt{c}$ as $x \to \infty$), nor for $y=kx$ or $y=x^k$ with $0 \lt k \lt 1$ (both increase without limit as $x \to \infty$) so what makes you think it might be true?  Perhaps with $y \to 0$ or $x-y \to 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no restriction on $y$, the statement is false. For instance, take $y=\sqrt{x}$. Then, $x > \sqrt{x}$ and as $x\to\infty$
$$
\sqrt{x-y} - \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)
= \sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2} + o(1) - \sqrt{x} + \sqrt[4]{x} = \sqrt[4]{x} + o(\sqrt[4]{x}) \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \infty
$$

---

What you *can* show, for instance, is that if $\frac{y}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0$ (i.e., $y=o(x)$ when $x\to\infty$) then
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x-y} - \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)
&= \sqrt{x}-\frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} +o\left(\max\big(\frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}}, \sqrt{y}\big)\right) \\
&= -\frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{y} +o\left(\max\big(\frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}}, \sqrt{y}\big)\right)
\end{align}$$
(Furthermore, since $y = o(x)$ we can further simplify as $\sqrt{x-y} - \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right) = \sqrt{y} +o\left(\sqrt{y}\right)$, since $y/\sqrt{x} = o(\sqrt{y})$)

Comment: Can you explain why the first equality $\sqrt{x-y}=\sqrt{x}+{1\over2}+o(1)$ hold?

Comment: Sure. $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} = \sqrt{x}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+o(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})\right) = \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2} + o(1)$.

Comment: Isn't $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: Yes, one sign was flipped -- it should be $-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With $y=\alpha x<x$,

$$\sqrt{x-\alpha x}-\sqrt x+\sqrt{\alpha x}=\Theta(\sqrt x).$$

Comment: It suffices to notice that the expression is homogenous of degree $1/2$.

Comment: The above is for $\alpha$ constant, though -- in general, you will get $\sqrt{y}$ in the $\Theta(\cdot)$.

Comment: @ClementC.: what use is this remark ?

Comment: My point is, your conclusion may be misleading if you do not specify that $\alpha$ is a constant. If I plug in $\alpha=\frac{1}{x^{1/10}}$, the quantity is *not* $\Theta(\sqrt{x})$. As written, though, this would look like a perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: @ClementC. splitting hairs.

Comment: Well, if you think so... I've seen (and made) many mistakes due to this sort of things. It may be clear from context to you that $\alpha$ is constant; it might not be to everyone.

Comment: This is deemed obvious from the equality, as $\alpha$ disappears. But actually it is enough to state that the homogeneous exponent is positive.